# syntax error unterminated quoted string in dockerfile

Tags: docker, consul

I created a Dockerfile that looks as follow:

```
FROM consul

COPY config-file.json /consul/config

ENTRYPOINT ["consul", "agent, "-config-file=/consul/config/config-file.json"]
```

The config( config-file.json) file that looks as follow:

```
{
  "datacenter": "microservices",
  "data_dir": "/opt/consul",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "disable_host_node_id" : true, 
  "server": true,
  "bootstrap_expect" : 2,
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "ui": true,
  "bind_addr": "192.168.70.20"
}
```

then run the container and got following:

```
dockerizer@docker1:~/consul$ docker run --rm -ti --network=host servery
/bin/sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a quote in your ENTRYPOINT after the word "agent".

`ENTRYPOINT ["consul", "agent", "-config-file=/consul/config/config-file.json"]`

This missing quote is what's causing the unterminated quote message, so the evaluated or executed ENTRYPOINT appears as `consul agent "-config-file=/consul/config/config-file.json` (which is missing a quote)